# "Claim has received" or "was received"?

Tags: tenses, passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs

I am a medical claim collector. So most of the time I'm making calls to insurance companies and make notes.

I used to write my comment as "The claim has received on 01.01.2018" but yesterday my supervisor asked me not to use "has" and use "was" instead.

I wanna know whats the correct form and the differences between in both,

> Claim has received on 01.01.2018

and

> Claim was received on 01.01.2018

Comment: Only the person/s or other 'recipients' ("The car received a number of mechanical upgrades") receive things. Your supervisor is totally correct, Kavinda, but this level of question should be accompanied by research and might then be suitable on our sister site ELL. It's off-topic here.

Comment: You could also write **The claim has been received** to confirm its arrival but do not include the time or date.

Comment: Just say "claim received [date]," but if you have to use a full verb, "was received." Back in the days when everyone used rubber stamps, the abbreviation "rec'd" was used.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is "was received". "To receive" implies that someone didn't have something before but now has it:

> John has received a letter [a minute ago]

You can turn this around and write it in passive form:

> The letter has been received by John

Or, in the past form:

> The letter was received [by John]

This is the construction you should be using in your case. [The] claim was received in the past, at a specific time.

The first form, Claim has received..., implies that it is the claim who now has something it didn't have before.

Comment: I agree however that this kind of question should be asked in ELL

Comment: cool.. nice explanation, Can I move the question to ELL?
I checked this in ginger also. But that even gave me an error. That's why I post the quiz. Anyway understood the mistake.

Answer (score -1):

What your supervisor suggested you was right.

Firstly, let's see why your version of the sentence was wrong?

> Claim has received on 01.01.2018.

This sentence formation suggests that the *Claim* is an actor; meaning that the Claim did receive **something** on 01.01.2018.

Obviously, Claim can not receive anything in reality. It can be received.

The correction your supervisor suggested to you transformed the statement in passive voice.

> Claim was received on 01.01.2018.

The actor in the above sentence is actually a hidden part.

> Claim was received **by an executive** on 01.01.2018.

The **by an executive** part can be omitted considering the context of the discussion.

Comment: nice one. Understood. I used to write "Claim has been received by the carrier on 01.01.2018" then recently I shorten the sentence to "Claim has received on "

Comment: The claim can receive something, it would be correct to say "This claim has received attention from our loss adjusters." However the claim had to be received by the loss adjusters before they could give it the attention. The OP's supervisor is correct.

Comment: @KavindaPrabhath You just shortened it too far and took out part of the verb. Saying "Claim has been received on 01.01.2018" is grammatical, however "Claim was received 01.01.2018" is more usual. In fact you could write "Claim received 01.01.2018" which is quite acceptable for the sort of note you are making even though it is not, strictly, grammatical.